# Invisible audio files

Tags: android, audio, android-sdcard

I am developing the application which is also downloading and saving mp3 files on SD card (it isn't main task of the application). These files I am using only in the application. Is some possible way to make these files invisible for users, especially for their audio players? For example when I open embedded player on Sony phones, so there are these mp3 files automaticly loaded - I don't want it.Thank you for help. Lukas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create [.nomedia](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#SavingSharedFiles) empty file in the folder where you saved your mp3 files:

> Include an empty file named .nomedia in your external files directory
>   (note the dot prefix in the filename). This will prevent Android's
>   media scanner from reading your media files and including them in apps
>   like Gallery or Music.

Answer (score 0):

Use internal storage of application by using `Context.MODE_PRIVATE`, that way your app will be the only one with access to these files. See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html), it should help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your files using `MODE_PRIVATE` as described in this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Or do as stated in this side-note of above-mentioned documentation:

> **Hiding your files from the Media Scanner**
>
> Include an empty file named .nomedia in your external files directory
>   (note the dot prefix in the filename). This will prevent Android's
>   media scanner from reading your media files and including them in apps
>   like Gallery or Music.

Comment: Can I use the MODE_PRIVATE also in external storage?

Comment: I think not. Docu says: _Files saved to the external storage are world-readable and can be modified by the user when they enable USB mass storage to transfer files on a computer._

Answer (score 0):

**There are tow options for you.**

1) Encrypt the files that you store on sdcard and again decrypt it before use it.

2) Create .nomedia file in exteral storage directory folder where you saved your mp3 files.

**Using Second option** The files will still be accessible from your original app or an explorer like Astro or Linda but prevent Android's media scanner from reading your media files and including them in apps like Gallery or Music.